# How can I make a build fail in a VS2010 modeling project with a missing referenced assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a VS 2010 modeling project with a layer diagram. I use the layer diagram to validate some assemblies. Note that I am adding assembly referenced to the modeling project, not project references, due to some build constraints I have. This works fine as long as the referenced assemblies can be found. When an assembly is not found, the build passes but a warning is issued indicating that a referenced assembly is not found. This makes perfect sense. However, if you expect the build to fail when there is a layer diagram validation error, a passing build gives the false impression that the implementation in the assembly was valid. My question is, how can I make the build fail when a referenced assembly is not found. I tried the TreatWarningsAsErrors tag but that did not work. I am not an MSBuild expert, but I think modeling projects work a little differently in that respect.

Thanks in advance for replies.

Fuat

Comment: I ended up writing an MSBuild custom task that takes the search paths and the list of referenced assemblies and checks if they all exist. If any of the assemblies does not exist, the task logs an error and returns false from the Execute method.

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the beforebuild target to have something like:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('C:\Reference\Required.dll')" Text="Reference not found" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried something like that. But the problem is that I have multiple reference dlls and the list can change. Also, these dlls can be resolved from several possible locations. Therefore, the Exists condition does not really work. I wish it took a list of files. The ResolveAssemblyReference target does all the work but it only issues a warning when it fails to find an assembly. I need an error.

Comment: You could it pass the reference itemgroup. Then its dynamic. Use %(Reference.FullPath)

Comment: I tried that as well. Because there are several locations where the referenced dlls can be found, the project file does not specify a location for a reference. Thus, %(Reference.FullPath) does not resolve to a correct location but to the project folder. Even if the referenced dll exists in one of these locations, I get a failure because %(Reference.FullPath) points to something wrong. Is there a way to create a list by combining search paths and assembly names? If there is, then I can use  Exists to search against such a list.